# How can I interpret two outputs in the Johansen cointegration tests

Tags: time-series, econometrics, cointegration

I got two "weird" (for me) outputs of the Johansen cointegration test with two different groups of variables (each group with three endogenous variables).

This is the first

```
Number of equations = 3
Lag order = 3
Estimation period: 1959 - 2018 (T = 59)
Case 3: Unrestricted constant
Exogenous regressor(s): oilcrisis fincrisis
Log-likelihood = 331.473 (including constant term: 164.038)
Cointegration tests, ignoring exogenous variables
Rank Eigenvalue Trace test  p-value  Lmax test  p-value
   0    0.33796     37.334 [0.0050]     24.333 [0.0149]
   1    0.11720     13.001 [0.1149]     7.3546 [0.4569]
   2   0.091260     5.6461 [0.0175]     5.6461 [0.0175]
```

As you can see, the p-value in the first row indicates one cointegration vector, the second rejects the existence of two cointegration vectors and the third indicates there there are three cointegration vectors. How to interpret this (of course all the endogenous variables are I(1))?

The second case is,

```
Number of equations = 3
Lag order = 2
Estimation period: 1960 - 2018 (T = 59)
Case 3: Unrestricted constant
Exogenous regressor(s): oilcrisis fincrisis
Log-likelihood = 539.75 (including constant term: 369.477)
Cointegration tests, ignoring exogenous variables
Rank Eigenvalue Trace test  p-value  Lmax test  p-value
   0    0.19713     25.670 [0.1429]     13.173 [0.4508]
   1    0.12565     12.497 [0.1354]     8.0566 [0.3814]
   2   0.071328     4.4400 [0.0351]     4.4400 [0.0351]
```

Here the test indicates that there aren't 1, neither 2 cointegration vectors. However, it indicates there are three cointegration vectors. How to interpret this?

Comment: The Johansen procedure is sequential - you stop testing once you cannot reject the null of at most as many cointegrating relationships. Also, do you mean "weird"? If not, please re-edit.

Comment: Dear Christoph, very much thank you for you quick reply